# Problem with setState adding an object to an array based off textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

So quick and short of the problem. I'm building a step wizard tool for users to create custom templates. There are multiple steps that take text input from the user, my application knows which step the user is entering data on and assigns a `stepid` to that piece of text.
The problem I'm having is putting that data in state so that I can post it to an API based on a specific format. Here is an example of what I want that data to look like:

```
state: {
   steps : [
         {templateStepId : 'this will be the number' , data: 'this will be 
         the message'},

         {templateStepId : 'this will be the number' , data: 'this will be 
         the message'} //there could be multiple text inputs each 
                        corresponding with a different stepId
          ]
```

Here is an example of my code:

```js
        addMsg = (msg , stepId) =>{
        let message = this.state.message
        message[stepId] = msg
        this.setState({message})
        this.setState( prevState => ({
            steps: [...prevState.steps,  {templateStepId: stepId, data : msg}]
        }));
    }`
Ignore the first setState, thats for something else. 
But here is where my text is coming from in another component: 

    handleChange = (text, type) =>{
        this.props.addMsg(text, type)
    }



    render() {

        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <AppBar title = {this.props.text}/>
                    <TextField
                    placeholder = {this.props.text}
                    onChange = {(e) => {this.handleChange(e.target.value , e.target.name)}}
                    name= {this.props.templateStepId}
                    id = 'msg'
                    />
                    <Navigation {...this.props} ></Navigation>
                </React.Fragment>
            </MuiThemeProvider>


        )}
```

I've also tried this as a solution for my add message component:

```
 let newStep = {templateStepId : stepId , data: msg}
    this.setState({
        steps : [newStep]
    })
```

The previous code here works well and gives me the state object I want, but as soon as the user moves to another text input component it gets completely overwritten.

Edit per request, here is where the component is being called within the step wizard. As you can see there is just the one text input component called message. This component could be called multiple times depending on the stepId coming from the API which is why the stepId changes for each input.

```
<MuiThemeProvider>
    <React.Fragment>
        <StepWizard >

        {
            this.props.templateSteps.map((data, idx) => {


            if (data.stepTypeId === "dc448967-7fad-42cf-8706-bbe1d124ceac") {

                return <Message
                addMsg = {this.props.addMsg}
                text = {data.name}
                templateStepId = {data.templateStepId}
                message = {this.props.message}
                startOver = {() => {this.props.startOver()}}
                key={idx}
            />
```

Here is my state from the console in devtools : 
[image: Current state during text input]

So as you can see, it's creating a new object for each letter input. I would appreciate any help at this point as I'm beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out!

Comment: As you've already said, "it's creating a new object for each letter". That is because of how the `change` event works: It fires for every change. And since you don't update the object with the current step ID but always create a new one, you end up with a bunch of old versions in your state.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly how I would go about that...

Comment: show where you are using this component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handleChange is getting called every time you make a change to the input. This is adding one more step to the state. You could check if the stepId is existing in the state and add data to that stepId only.If the stepId is not present you can add a record.

```js
function getStepIdIndex(arr, id) {

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].templateStepId === id) {

      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

let addMsg = (msg, stepId) => {
  let stepIdIndex = getStepIdIndex(this.state.steps, stepId);
  if (stepIdIndex === -1) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      steps: [...prevState.steps, {
        templateStepId: stepId,
        data: msg
      }]
    }));
  } else {
    this.state.steps[stepIdIndex].data=msg;
    this.setState({steps:[...this.state.steps]});
}
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I don't know why I didn't think to write another function to check for a matching Id.